# SQL WHERE Clause - How to Have the Referenced Word/Number Changed Based on User Inputted Data

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

On this site (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), it shows how to use the "Where" clause based on a certain word or number referenced.  For instance, in this case the word "Mexico".

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico';
```

How do you use a "Where" clause if you want the word being referenced (in this case 'Mexico') to be changed depending on what a user inputs in a field?

Could you provide an example in PHP?

Comment: Some code please? PHP or VB orc C# ?

Answer (score -1):

Example in VB:

```
'TextBox1 is input field
Dim query As String
query= "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='" + TextBox1.text +"'"
```

Answer (score -1):

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE country= '".$country."'");